# Does a token generated using ADAL library to call our custom APIs, work even after AD Graph is deprecated - (which as of now is June 30, 2023)?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api, adal

We are using ADAL library's AuthenticationContext object to acquire token. The "Authority" we are using is "login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-Id}. The token is then used to call our custom APIs, not Azure AD API or Microsoft Graph API.

I know that ADAL is being deprecated on June 30, 2023.

My question is: Will the token that is generated using ADAL like above, stop working after the deprecation date? Please note, we are not calling Azure AD API or Microsoft Graph API. Just our own backend APIs which authenticate using the JWT token. I assume not but wanted to get a confirmation, if my assumption is correct.

Answer (score 0):

ADAL is just a client side library for the Azure AD (v1.0) authentication endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens. That endpoint isn't getting any new features hence Microsoft have depreciate the library because there isn't anything new to add or change and they want you to use the v2.0 (or Microsoft identity Platform). The Azure v1.0 endpoint hasn't been depreciate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-deprecated-azure-ad (but this may change at any point in the future but you should get enough time to move). The biggest problem you may have if there is an underlying security flaw in the library or one of its dependencies this can put your app at risk (it can also act as an upgrade blocker in your app) so it's best to plan and move away from the library as quickly as you can.